# Phonegap add notification push with firebase

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I'm searching for a way to push notification on my phonegap android app.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search would get you your answer, there are MULTIPLE ones to choose from, I found this one to be favorably easy to use [cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)